# Comparing values in one array with the values in a second with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays that look something like this:

```
const classes = ["story-body-text", "story-content", "leading__100"];
const prefixes = ["alignment__", "font__", "leading__", "size__", "tracking__", "features__"];
```

I need to loop through the `classes` array and remove any values that don’t begin with a value from the `prefixes` array. In this particular instance it should return a new array with the value of:

```
return ["leading__100"];
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you think of a way you might tackle this? Suppose you weren't using Lodash and had to write plain JavaScript for it. Could you create a new output array, then loop through your `classes` array, and for each element in that array loop through all of the `prefixes` and see if one matches, and if it does, push the current `classes` element to the output array and break out of that inner loop?

Comment: Heya Michael. I see that’s the logical approach, but I was concerned with looping through two arrays for this. I guess there isn’t really a way around that, huh?

Comment: Yeah, if you were checking for a full string match, you could create an object with each of the values from the `prefixes` array (which wouldn't be called `prefixes` in this case, of course) and then in your outer loop you would just check for the existence of the current `classes` value in that object. That would avoid the nested loops and could be faster in a case with a lot of elements. But with the prefix match, anything you do will pretty much boil down to the nested loops (in one form or another).

Comment: For a Lodash solution, you might look at `_.filter()` for the outer loop on the `classes` array. Pass it a predicate function that checks each of the prefixes. That predicate function could use `_.some()` on the `prefixes` array and check `string.startsWith()` on each element. (Or for wider browser support, use the equivalent code found in the [MDN `.startsWith()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). But if speed may be a concern, the two nested `for` loops will win.

Answer (score 0):

```
_.filter(classes, cls => _.some(prefixes, p => _.startsWith(cls, p)))
```